# Google Calendar API limited usage issue

Tags: google-calendar-api

We are doing an integration with Google Calendar Api, trying to publish events in a calendar, and then add them to the invited users (attendees) in their primary calendars. After doing a couple of tests and publications we skip the error message:

> Calendar usage limits exceeded. [403]

We have read the documentation and the limits of petitions, but we are not passing at any time of that limit, and we skip the same error. We have seen in forums and in the same documentation of the API, that the reasons can be diverse, like the publication of more than 25 calendars, overcome the 10,000 events, etc.

In our case, we do not overcome any of those limitations. To get an idea, we did not surpass the 200 events in a couple of days. And since we started testing, events don't exceed 500. That is why we are trying to contact you as the last solution, because we do not know where the problem is.

Is there are any daily or sendings attendees exact limits ? Because we need to launch and update many of them, and don't know how to do it. How can we publish and share this events without having the limitation failure? In our Google Console we say that the quota still remain 1.000.000 queries per day.

To make myself understood, my procedure is: I have a general Calendar with a Json Keys, and I publish all my events in it. Then, I trying to add attendees and publish(share) part of my events with them. But I have the same error for days. I know that Google Calendar limits the number of invitations a user can send to external guests 100-300 guests exactly. But I do not know if is a limit per hours, days, or account? How we can do to publish many events with attendees without limits? Is there a solution for that?

Comment: "That is why we are trying to contact you as the last solution" - your Stack Overflow readers understand that Google have probably sent you here in their help material. However, your readers are not Google (Tech Support). They may be able to advise, but be aware that mostly, you are not talking to Google themselves, except in the (rarer) cases where a Google employee comes here (and identifies themselves as such).

Comment: You may wish to send your issue to Google themselves, if you can find a way past the robot sentries. They may not fix it for you, but perhaps it will alert them to a problem if many people in your position make similar reports.

Answer (score 1):

As can be read in [this post](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2006298-google-calendar-and-the-200-person-limitation), besides what is written in the documentation itself, this is a hard limitation from Google to stop spammers.

Currently there is no real solution and it's up to Google. There are rumors that Google is trying to tackle this issue but nothing has changed in the mean time.

Basically, your only option is either to wait and see what Google does with this or abandon their solution and find an alternative.

Comment: Is it possible for the OP to slow their posting e.g. no more than one event creation every 30 seconds? That would be awkward, but at least it might be a workaround.

Comment: It will take 2.5 hours to send only 300 invitations. It is also problematic to test since every time you go over the limit you get a timeout for several hours.

Comment: That'd still work - if I am reading the post correctly, the OP only has 500 maximum, and usually 200. I agree the situation is not ideal, but if the OP _has_ to use Google _and_ there is no solution, then rate-limiting is the last option on the table. I wonder if a try-and-variable-backoff strategy would work?

Comment: "you get a timeout for several hours" - ouch.